# my node.js socket.io simple server dosen't work when run by docker run

Tags: node.js, docker

When I run by type directly `npm start` or `node index.js` the `127.0.0.1:4444` site page is successfully opened. But, if I use Docker to make it possible to run with EC2, it could run in my PC but can't open the site `127.0.0.1:4444`.

here's my code.

**index.js**

```
var app = require('http').createServer(handler)
var fs = require('fs');

app.listen(4444);

function handler (req, res) {
  fs.readFile(__dirname + '/index.html',
  function (err, data) {
      if (err) {
      res.writeHead(500);
           return res.end('Error loading index.html');
      }

      res.writeHead(200);
      res.end(data);
  });
}

var io = require('socket.io')(app);

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
  console.log('Hello, socket.io~');
});
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM node:12

COPY package.json /src/package.json

RUN cd /src

RUN npm install

RUN npm install socket.io

COPY . /src

WORKDIR /src

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "hahaha",
  "version": "12.19.0",
  "description": "my first socket.io",
  "main": "index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "socket.io": "^2.3.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {},
  "scripts": {
    "start" : "node index.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

**.dockerignore**

```
node_modules/
```

and full path image
[path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wYQWt.png)

please help me.

Comment: How are you starting the container?

Comment: Make sure you are opening port 4444 on your container by adding the -p 4444:4444 option on your docker run command. Also, for completeness use EXPOSE 4444 on your docker file.

Comment: I did, but it dosen't work stil. sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try exposing the port 4444 in the dockerfile.

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#expose

Answer (score 0):

when Mario's answer - EXPOSE 4444 - and camba1's answer - -p 4444:4444 - it didn't worked,  but when I use it both - that means, I wrote EXPOSE 4444 and build run -p 4444:4444. -